# How to configure datasource in persistence.xml file itself?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

The answer of this question will be very helpful for me to resolve my previous question.

[here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23219428/could-not-complete-schema-update-java-lang-unsupportedoperationexception-the-a?noredirect=1#comment35552242_23219428)

I am trying simple Spring-MVC (with JPA) application. I want to include every necessary connection values in persistence.xml file only. In my application there are only 2 XMl files.

1) web.xml and 2) persistence.xml

Please check my previous question ( [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23219428/could-not-complete-schema-update-java-lang-unsupportedoperationexception-the-a?noredirect=1#comment35552242_23219428)) for errors and persistence.xml file.

I am searching on net but not getting proper answer.
Please help me. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Why do you not want to have a spring configuration file?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spring / springMVC then you need to configure the datasource in the spring application context xml file only. All your contents from persistence.xml should be placed in the spring application context xml. Because spring is the core base framework which manages hibernate.

Check this http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring3-mvc-hibernate-maven-tutorial-eclipse-example/

In this example its configured in spring-servlet.xml